# How to click on the list of the <li> elements in an <ul> elements with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

I tried to select 2002 in dropdown menu.
It doesn't work at any late.
I used xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/main/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/section/div[3]/fieldset/div[7]/dl[1]/dd/ul/li[1]/a").click()
```

but it doesn't work..I tried all the solutions I got...
How can I select this?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work?? Is there any exception?? I this menu item present after clicking on dropdown?? Are you able to show this dropdown item ??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur What I mean was...not clickable..yes I clicked on the dropdown after I tried to choose 2002.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur but your code works perfectly~!! you are the best ~! thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're able to open dropdown item but unable to click on item, you should try using [`Explicit Waits`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) with `WebDriverWait` to wait until this element is visible and enable to click as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul#ulBirthYear a[data-value='2002']")))
element.click()
```

Or

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "2002")))
element.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, try to avoid using absolute XPATH.
Use something like this:

```
'//ul[@id="uiBirthYear"]/li/a[@data-value="2002"]'
```

Also ensure, that the DOM is fully built, before you trying to get/click on this element.

Try to set an *implicit wait*

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

or an *explicit wait* (read more: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@id="uiBirthYear"]/li/a[@data-value="2002"]"}

Comment: try `'data-value="2002"' in driver.page_source` to ensure, that such element exists (or just take a screenshot)

Comment: How can I upload the image?