# Navigating to next page of a javascript table using python selenium chrome webdriver

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

My goal is to loop through each of the pages and scrape the contents into a DataFrame. So far, I can get the first 20 no problem. I cannot seem to figure out how to navigate to the next page on a javascript table using python selenium chrome webdriver. Have tried a few of the solutions (below seems like the closest) but cannot replicate the result. I would post the website but it is one where you need log in credentials to access. Provided a page source screenshot for the relevant ul and li elements

stackoverflow solution tried:
[How to click on the list of the <li> elements in an <ul> elements with selenium in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097838/how-to-click-on-the-list-of-the-li-elements-in-an-ul-elements-with-selenium)

Am able to get the first 20 rows using:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="allPicksId"]/div/div[2]').text`

Then, when trying to get the next rows on next table page using the code below I get an exception:

```py
next_table_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ant-pagination-next"))).click()

Yields this exception:
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (546, 996)
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

[Page Source Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOqrR.png)

[Table Page Navigation Bar Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWizR.png)

Comment: did u tried the button instead of li `ant-pagination-item-link` ? as they shared on same space ..then next attempt would be to hit span area.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out by using the code below:

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ant-pagination-next')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop to handle this

example:

```
for I in range(1, 23):
      driver.find_element_by_xpath().click()
```

Or

you can use the site URL to go next page

[see this url](https://ibb.co/4NW54Jq)

[and second url](https://ibb.co/FVXGPfR)

now you must change the number of pages to go next page

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no page number in the URL. It is all navigated based on the buttons. I plan on just using a loop whenever I figure out how to get to the next table page

Comment: send XPath  of pages 18, 19, 20, 21, 22

Comment: I got the final page number text extracted and used a while loop to control the amount of clicks for the next page button to terminate once the end page number is reached. Took a little digging but finally got the answer to my question and posted it above.