# Cant select a <li element from a dropdon menu using the Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, click

I'm trying to click on the filter menu on an e-commerce page using selenium and then sort the reviews on the product page by recent.

I have managed opened the menu using the following code

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()


url="https://www.daraz.pk/products/candy-by-haier-1-ton-heat-cool-dc-inverter-white-colour-ac-csu-12hp10-years-brand-warranty-i276904502-s1494701276.html?spm=a2a0e.seller.list.2.18b049aahnIdR0&mp=1"
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()


browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#module_product_review > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(3)").click()
```

however when i try to click an option from the dropdown menu using the following code

```
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'body > div:nth-child(49) > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(2)').click()
```

i keep getting the error

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body > div:nth-child(49) > div > div"}

This is the HTML for the drop down-(Sorry, I'm new to coding and don't know how to copy the html and paste it here, attaching an image instead

[HTML Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqMcS.png)

Ive tried multiple solutions including the solution in this question

[How to click on the list of the <li> elements in an <ul> elements with selenium in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097838/how-to-click-on-the-list-of-the-li-elements-in-an-ul-elements-with-selenium)

Nothing seems top be working and i cant figure why it wont detect an element on either XPATH or CSS detector. I've even tried using LINK_NAME and PARTIAL_LINK_NAME and i run into the same issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use "WebDriverWait" to wait until the page is being rendered

try this code :

```
import time

import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()


url="https://www.daraz.pk/products/candy-by-haier-1-ton-heat-cool-dc-inverter-white-colour-ac-csu-12hp10-years-brand-warranty-i276904502-s1494701276.html?spm=a2a0e.seller.list.2.18b049aahnIdR0&mp=1"
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()


xpath= r'//*[@id="module_product_review"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]'
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()

time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: this worked! can you explain why you imported the requests library?